# At same level do these two pipe lines give same pressure of water?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, classical-mechanics

Provided that the two pipe lines are of same length, same material and in the same level, is the water pressure in both the layouts same or different?

[image]

PS: In 1st pipeline the turns are not "upward-downward" turns but "sideward-turns" in same level(height).

Comment: The friction in the first pipe would give a very small heating effect then increasing the pressure a little bit more

Answer (score 3):

**Static pressure** will be the same, even if one pipe would be only half as long as the other one. That's due to Pascal's Law:

$ \Delta P = \rho \cdot g \cdot \Delta h $

So the pressure difference is proportional with difference in height, and for all points at the same height the pressure will be the same.

**Dynamic pressure** will be lower for the #2, as there won't be the same pressure loss due to the resistance difference.

A fluid with sufficiently high viscosity (most liquids) will have a laminar flow in pipe #2, whereas the bends in #1 will break the lamina and cause turbulence at the bends which increases flow resistance.

Comment: Why will static pressure be the same? Are you sure for #2 dynamic pressure ($0.5 \rho v^2$) will be *lower*? Anyway, some argumentation based on physical laws would be nice.

Comment: you do use some awkward notion for static an dynamic pressure. You mean by "static pressure" the pressure difference when flow rate is zero (water doesn't move), and by "dynamic pressure" the pressure on the exit when the water is flowing. But ok, it doesn't matter much.

Comment: @Yrogirg - What terminology should I use then?

Comment: pressure drop (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_drop) To distinct the cases just specify "water (not) flowing". Usually by static pressure meant the pressure $p$ itself at point and by dynamic pressure $\frac{1}{2} \rho v^2$ or $p + \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2$ at a point.

Comment: @Yrogirg - But "pressure drop" indicates a difference, dynamic pressure can be absolute, and at any point, BTW, not just at the exit. The dynamic pressure equation you quote is a function of velocity, so that's flowing, right?

Comment: everything in your comment is absolutely right and I don't understand that "but". Is there some contradiction?

Comment: The dynamic pressure drop is not necessarily less after a turn, and turns don't break laminar flows in general. You can have a laminar turn no problem, at low enough Reynolds number, it's automatic.

Answer (score 1):

**1st pipe:** Practically speaking, there would be an *appreciable* change of pressure definitely at initial water flow due to the collision of water molecules on the different turns of the pipe. But as dynamic pressure comes into play, the pressure would remain constant and the water flow is even...

**2nd pipe:** The pressure *remains the same* for a horizontal pipe with no turns...

Comment: To your understanding it is not "upward-downward" turns but "sideward-turns" in same level(height)

Comment: how can pressure vary for upward and downward turns whens they are in same level? It would be same pressure even if its right turn or left turn. no?

Comment: So here you are talking about "vertical-vs-horizontal", in my question I talk only about horizontal with right and left bends. ok?

Comment: its obvious,  Flows

Answer (score 0):

As long as the fluid is same, the pressure at same heights is always equal.

Answer (score 0):

The pressure drop in your first diagram will be substantially higher due to the bends. There is an extra pressure drop for either laminar for turbulent flow at every bend which will add to the overall pressure drop if the pipe were straight. There are standard engineering formula to use for pressure drop due to bends in the pipe.